# NSFetchedResultsController and getting the grouping right

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

I have the following problem. I have a UITableview that is powered by an NSFetchedResultsController.
It should display let's say a projects, folders and files. There is no bigger hierarchy than that. So a project has several folders and those have several files.
Now my table view should display those files, grouped by folders.

So i thought my fetch requests' predicate would simply be:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"folder.project = %@", self.project];
```

I would then use MagicalRecord to make an NSFetchedResultsController by making something like this:

```
[File fetchAllGroupedBy:@"folder.name"
          withPredicate:sectionPredicate
               sortedBy:@"folder.name"
              ascending:YES];
```

This basically works with one big problem... if there is no file in the folder, I wouldn't get a section for that folder (which I need!!!!)

So what I need is the tableview to also display section headers for empty folders:

```
Folder A
  File 1
  File 2
Folder B
Folder C
  File 3
```

I could do it without the NSFetchedResultsController, but I love that it handles the inserting/deleting of rows and sections so nice and that it observes for changes...

Thx for helping,
Cheers,
Georg

Comment: I don't think there is a simple (or even medium-complicated) solution for that. A FRC does not create empty sections. You would have to modify the table view data source methods, but then the FRC index path and the table view index path are no longer in sync, which makes the FRC delegate methods (didChangeObject, ...) complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is indeed a bit complex. I will try and explain a partial solution (no nested folders, and not section sort order support)

Model changes:
1) set the parent entity of `Folder` to `File` (not necessary if you use a dummy item).
2) add the BOOL field `isFinal` to `File` entity.
3) generate the class files for the entities.
4) in `Folder.h` implement `-awakeFromInsert` like this:

```
- (void) awakeFromInsert
{
    self.isFinal = YES;
    self.folder = self;//You could also fabricate a dummy item
}
```

FetchedResultsController:
1) set your fetch request like so:

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"File"];
NSSortDescriptor* terminalSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"isFinal" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor* nameSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[terminalSort,nameSort]];
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"folder.project == %@",project]]
//Any additional settings
```

2) initialise your FRC like so :

```
self.fetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"folder"//or @"folder.<some unique property>"
                                               cacheName:nil];
```

notice that the `sectionNameKeyPath` is set to `folder`, and not `folder.name` to support folders with the same name (if this is not required, and folder name is unique, use `folder.name` )

3) in your `-controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` add at the beginning of the method:

```
File* file = (File*)anObject;
if (file.isFinal) {
    return;
}
```

Table view:
1) implement:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects] - 1;
}
```

2) implement:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sec = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];

    return [[[[sec objects] objectAtIndex:0] folder] name];
}
```

This should give you the basic functionality you need.
To support a more complex behaviour, additional changes will be required.

Comment: Hey Dan,
Thanks for answering my question! So basically you are inserting a dummy item for each folder, which is himself?
The lack of not being able to sort my sections is bad tough... There wouldn't be a possibility to change that, would there be?

Comment: As i said, in order to sort the sections by folder name, the folder name would either MUST be unique, and you `sectionNameKeyPath` would be `folder.name`, or you will need to create a unique property for a folder to match your required sort order and make it your `sectionNameKeyPath`

Comment: Ah, ok... Well I did try out this solution and will check if I like it. The fact that I have to change my datamodel just so that the ViewController can display data the way he wants does not seem good to me. I have a version of a TableViewController in place that can take multiple FRCs and I guess I'll stick with that for now. When name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification is fired, I just update those FRCs. I loose my animation that way, but i'll figure out something. But that way I don't have to mess with my datamodel.

Anyway, Thank you a lot for helping!