# NSFetchRequest for sub objects in rows

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

My Data Model is as follows:
Category

—>name

—>items (Array of items of type "Car")

I am trying to fetch with section as name and rows should be items(which is a NSArray)

Here is my code, where I am expecting to return rows as Car but it still returning "Category". So, what could be a NSFetchRequest?

```
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Categories"];


NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];

fetchController=[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:delegate.managedContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"name" cacheName:nil];
NSError *fetchError;
[fetchController performFetch:&fetchError];
```

I have attached image of the model.

[image]

Code to fetch car is as follows.

```
AppDelegate *del=(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Car"];


NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];

fetchController=[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:del.managedContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"Categories.name" cacheName:nil];
NSError *fetchError;
[fetchController performFetch:&fetchError];
```

Code is uploaded here  https://www.dropbox.com/s/jjk0nve3pmytui2/TestAppData%202.zip

Note:- I am thinking to show empty section's as I have view for headers which has "Add" button. So, by this the user would know the number of categories easily.

To achieve things mentioned in the above "Note",I tried the following. I have created a `CarViewController2`. It creates number of sections, which are equal number of categories, but number of rows are dependent on the `categoriesRelationship`(which is a NSOrderedSet). One can test this by -uncommenting some code in `(IBAction) addCategory:(id)` sender of ViewController.m for testing. (Uncomment once , then comment again thereafter) Code has been updated and can be downloaded.

Please Correct the code if required. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup should be:

```
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Car"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"category.name" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];

fetchController=[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                    managedObjectContext:delegate.managedContext 
                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"category.name" 
                                                               cacheName:nil];
```

`category.name` assume that the reverse relationship for `Category` `items` is `Car` `category` (one-to-many relation)

Please note that you might want to change the sort descriptor to sort by some `Car` property

**Edit:**

After you posted your model and current code you cannot section your data by `Category` name, as it is a many-to-many relationship.
You cannot have duplicate items for different sections.

If `Car` 'c' belongs to categories 'g1' and 'g2' you would either need to build the data structure yourself or introduce an intermediary entity that link between car and categories and it will be the one the request will be base upon.

**Edit 2:**

In your project, you set your `carRelation` as to-one to a `Categories` entity this will allow you to form the following request:

```
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Car"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"carName" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];

fetchController=[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                    managedObjectContext:delegate.managedContext 
                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"carRelation.categoryName" 
                                                               cacheName:nil];
```

This would still not show categories with no cars in them (as it should as you have a cars view and a categories view).

**Edit 3:**

Your code corrections for `CarViewController.m`:

```
-(void) getData{
    AppDelegate *del=(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    NSFetchRequest *req=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Car"];
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor1=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"carRelationship.categoryName" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor2=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"carName" ascending:YES];
    [req setSortDescriptors:@[descriptor1,descriptor2]];
    fetchController=[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:req managedObjectContext:del.managedContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"carRelationship.categoryName" cacheName:nil];
    NSError *fetchError;
    fetchController.delegate=self;
    [fetchController performFetch:&fetchError];
    NSLog(@"Fetch ERROR= %@",fetchError);
}

- (NSString*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo=[[fetchController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo name];
}
```

As I explained before, **This would still not show categories with no cars in them**

Comment: I did add relationship, but it is not updating the core data model class, so I have to delete and recreate the class. Will it show a section list, if "Car" entity is empty. As there are Category which are still Present in the entity "Category"(ex. SUV and sportscar, etc). Can you please provide a example?

Comment: @andyPaul This will not result in empty sections (categories that have no cars in them). regenerate the class with the relationship (though adding it to the entity is enough), and set it when adding `Car` objects. what type of example would you like?

Comment: I have edited the code, please let me know if I need to specify anything else to resolve it.

Comment: @andyPaul You should sort by `carName` property which is the property defined in your `Car` entity.

Comment: It crashes while fetching.

Comment: I have uploaded my project at https://www.dropbox.com/s/j6yrz63nibjxx5v/TestAppData.zip . You can add few categories by clicking on "+" button. In "MyCars" tab it should show section even if a category does not have car's.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. If possible can you please correct the code and send me the link.

Comment: That's true. I was hoping it will list all sections but with no rows(even if cars are not available). But, now as per observation and the same thing implemented by me, we see section is only visible only if it has Cars in it.

Comment: Is there any way to have it, like category with empty sections?

Comment: Why would you want to show the user sections he cannot access and contain no information when you have another view just for that?

Comment: For user it will be easy to see number of categories , and then tap on section add button.

Comment: You can show the number in the title. Add a `Category` in a `Car` view sounds inconsistent. To achieve this you will have to add a "dummy" `Car` object to each `Category` see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064051/nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-getting-the-grouping-right/16088352#16088352) for something similar.

Comment: I understood, the solution you had give, but can you please send me in the project which I had shared.

Comment: @andyPaul The project is [HERE](https://github.com/infradust/CarCategoryTest) it will be deleted in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try

```
NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Category"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];
fetchController=[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request   managedObjectContext:delegate.managedContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"name" cacheName:nil];
NSError *fetchError;
[fetchController performFetch:&fetchError];

NSArray *categories = [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
for(Category *c in categories){
   NSSet *items = c.items;// array that you want
}
```

Comment: performFetch populates the array, the number of section and rows are set with fetchController. The solution which you provided will not work , with my existing code.

Comment: @andyPaul: performFetch return BOOL not the array. NSArray *categories = [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] -> What do you get categories? Array of what?